# https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap Not working in device

Tags: cordova, oauth, phonegap-plugins

I have tried "`https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap`" plugin by adding from CLI with "`cordova plugin add https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap`". Its working perfectly in browser but not working in devices.

I have tried "`alert(OAuth.getVersion());`". Its displaying `web-*` in browser and `phonegap-*` in devices. But the request for popup is not going.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have missed to include cordova.js file. Once I include that its working perfectly.